# Volley StringRequest not inserting data in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-volley

I am trying to insert user input in firebase and am using Volley. But nothing being inserted in firebase.Below is the code -

```
                String url = "https://zimber-69c82.firebaseio.com/";

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(StringRequest.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://zimber-69c82.firebaseio.com/users");
                        if (response.equals("null")) {
                            firebase.child(user).child("password").setValue(pass);
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                                if (!object.has(user)) {
                                    firebase.child(user).child("password").setValue(pass);
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Your code is using Volley to **read** data from Firebase, and then using a *very old version of the* Firebase SDK to **write** data to the database. Which of these isn't working? If you step through the code, and set breakpoints, which line is being reached, and which line isn't doing what you expect it to do? Also: are there any error message being logged? What is `response` (if you ever get a response`?

Comment: okay i set beakpoints at                         Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://zimber-69c82.firebaseio.com/users");
 and at                             firebase.child(user).child("password").setValue(pass);
and the response i get is "users".

Comment: That's the value of `firebase.toString()`. I mean what is the value in the `response` variable? Is that the JSON data you expect? Also: why are you using an SDK version that is 3+ years old? I highly recommend starting with a more recent version,  like the one referenced in the Firebase documentation on getting started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start